# Include php function inside a php class

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to extend a wordpress plugin with a custom field (which is generated by a plugin, too). This is an excerpt of the gallery-plugin-file I need to change:

```
<?php
class mg_overlay_manager {
    private $preview_mode = false;
    private $title_under = false;
    private $overlay;

    // image overlay 
    public $ol_txt_part = '<div class="cell_type"><span class="mg_overlay_tit">%MG-TITLE-OL%</span></div>';
    public $ol_code = '
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="cell_more"><span></span></div>
    ';

}
```

In this HTML-part

```
 public $ol_txt_part = '<div class="cell_type"><span class="mg_overlay_tit">%MG-TITLE-OL%</span></div>';
```

I need to insert

```
<?php the_field('city'); ?>
```

which will display my custom field in the frontend besides the %MG-TITLE-OL%.

My knowledge to php is very limited, so any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: where you want to add cty field? in a post or page ?

Comment: It's a custom post type in the wordpress backend generated by the plugin.
Pasting the <?php the_field('city'); ?> into single.php or page.php works flawless but I'm  not able to insert it in the code above.

Comment: ok ok i got it. add me on skype: harryr891 I will fix it

Comment: sorry i dont have skype atm